# Controlling multiple views in one controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-view

Following the MVC pattern, one controller should be able to handle multiple views in AngularJS.

E.g. I have one view for showing all users and one for creating a new user. My  `$routeProvider` (excerpt) looks like this:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/showusers', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/showusers.html',
        controller: 'userController'
      }).   
      when('/createuser', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/showusers.html',
        controller: 'userController'
      })
  }]);
```

Both views share several methods such as retrieving all user attributes. These shared methods are accessed through a `factory`.

The `userController` (excerpt) currently looks like this where `Users` is a factory:

```
angular.module('supportModule').
  controller('userController', function($scope, Users) {
    var init = function(){
      $scope.users = Users.getAll();
      $scope.attributes = Users.getAttributes();
    }
    init();
  })
```

The problem is: I don't need to request `Users.getAll();` when I'm on the `createuser` view.

Of course, I could easily parse the route by using `$location`, the `$routeProvider` or pure JS and then conditonally call methods - but I figure there is a more elegant and efficient way in Angular :)
Something like in typical MVC frameworks where one controller has many actions - one for each view.

So my question:
**How to elegantly call methods based on the view in a controller which controls more than one view?**

Comment: Check [`resolve`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider)

Comment: you can share the data between the controllers using the same factory which is sharing the methods... this way you wont have to do getAll again...

Comment: @HarishR Yes, I know that and I'm doing it. However, I would have two controllers again, so one controller for each view which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: in that case the only solution i can think of is having some parent html with ng-if/ng-include/ng-controller.. ui-router is much better for handling things like these...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `resolve:` when setup `$routeProvider` to pass values to a controller depending on the matched route.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/showusers', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/showusers.html',
        controller: 'userController',
        resolve: {
          ctrlOptions: function () {
            return {
              getAllUsers: true,
            };
          }
        }
      }).
      when('/createuser', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/showusers.html',
        controller: 'userController',
        resolve: {
          ctrlOptions: function () {
            return {
              getAllUsers: false,
            };
          }
        }
      })
  }]);
```

and then in the controller, you can inject item specified in `resolve:` like this:

```
app.controller('userController', function ($scope, Users, ctrlOptions) {
  var init = function () {
    if (ctrlOptions.getAllUsers) {
      $scope.users = Users.getAll();
    }

    $scope.attributes = Users.getAttributes();
  };

  init();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I haven't used `resolve` yet, but it seems to be pretty handy. For my example though, I don't see a big advantage over checking for the current route in the controller right away.

Comment: Sometimes you don't need to add resolve to every route, if you don't do so, angular will return unknown provider error. is there any way to avoid that or maybe another way to handle that case ?